# Apple effect Jquery not working

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I'm here again because of jquery overlay.

I have an overlay that loads a normal Div into it, i want to apply the apple effect to it, but i can't, i get an javascript error "Effect no found".

The code for the jquery function is written as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad() {
            var triggers = $("button.modalInput").overlay({
                // some expose tweaks suitable for modal dialogs
                expose: {
                    color: '#333',
                    loadSpeed: 200,
                    opacity: 0.3,
                    zIndex: 99
                },
                top: '15%',
                effect: 'apple',
                closeOnClick: false
            });
        } 
    </script>
```

That function when executed throws that error. If i remove the 'effect' line everything works fine but obviously without the effect.
Anyone who can help me ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the apple effect in a css file. See http://flowplayer.org/tools/css/overlay-apple.css for an example.

Comment: i have the css classes in my custom css almost exactly like that i only changed the name from apple_overlay to apple_overlayWhatever, does that change modifyes the entire logic? what can i do? thank you

Comment: @rolando: Yes, I believe if you change the name, then that will break the jquery logic. Go ahead and revert the name back to what the example css file has. If you still have problems, please post your css file.

Comment: i changed back the name to apple_overlay and i used the exact same css you defined in the link above (i changed the url of the images of course) and the problem still remains:  
  throw'Overlay: cannot find effect : "'+k.effect+'"'  
the thing is without the "effect: 'apple'" both css work perfectly so i guess the problem is in my jquery function. I can live without that effect, but it will be a plus for me.
Regards.

Comment: Then I am not sure what is going on. I would just suggest reading through http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/apple.html and making sure that you have everything done as shown there.

Comment: Good luck. Let me know how that goes. We should be able to figure this out some day :)